# DateTime objects not working with collection-if feature in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the Dart feature *Collection-if* introduced in *Dart 2.3*. My model class is

```
class Calendar {
  Calendar(
      {this.headerDate, this.releaseDate, this.period,this.title});

  final DateTime headerDate;
  final DateTime releaseDate;
  final String title;
  final String period;

  factory Calendar.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> value) {
    final int releaseDateMilliseconds = value['releaseDate'];
    final int headerDateMilliseconds= value['headerDate'];
    return Calendar(
      releaseDate: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(releaseDateMilliseconds),
      headerDate: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(headerDateMilliseconds),
      title: value['title'],
      period: value['period'],
    );
  }
}
```

The feature works fine when I'm dealing with *Strings* but doesn't work when I check for null for for the `DateTime` objects. The dates are stored as *numbers* in firestore and converted in to DateTime objects. Here is my build method:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      if(calendar.title!=null) /// Works
      Text(calendar.title),
      if(calendar.period!=null) ///Works
      Text(calendar.period),
      if(calendar.headerDate!=null) /// Doesn't work
      Text(Format.date(calendar.headerDate)),
      Text(Format.date(calendar.releaseDate)),
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? The headerDate value is coming null? Can you elaborate on the issue? Thank you

Comment: thanks, I thought I was using collection-if feature incorrectly but my problem was calling `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` on null. All good now.